# Как правильно структурировать многофайловую программу на с++?

Tags: c++, ооп, классы

Пишу небольшую имитация компьютера на с++, возник такой вопрос. Есть класс mySimpleComputer   в файле mySimpleComputer.cpp, для него есть заголовочный файл с тем же названием, в котором прописаны макросы. Как подключить эти файлы к main правильно, что бы использовать этот класс. Нужно ли подключать cpp файл, или класс нужно описывать в hpp файле, или как то ещё?

Comment: Обычно cpp файлы не подключают. Класс обычно помещают в hpp файл, а его реализацию помещают в cpp файл. Ну и потом подключают этот hpp файл к файлу с `main`, но компилировать нужно оба cpp файла.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Держите пример.

`main.cpp`:

```
#include <iostream>

#include "reporter.h"

int main() {
    Reporter r;
    std::cout << r.report() << '\n';
}
```

`reporter.h`:

```
#ifndef REPORTER_H_
#define REPORTER_H_

#include <string>

class Reporter {
public:
    std::string report();
};

#endif // REPORTER_H_
```

`reporter.cpp`:

```
#include "reporter.h"

std::string Reporter::report() {
    return "This is report.";
}
```

Собираем, запускаем:

> ```
> $ g++ -I. main.cpp reporter.cpp
>
> $ ./a.out 
> This is report.
> ```

Comment: Спасибо большое, пример очень помог

Comment: @lidar, поправил. Спасибо!

Answer (score 2):

Стандартной практикой в программах на C или C++ заключается в том, что мы храним все объявления классов, констант, макросов, глобальных переменных и прототипов функций в файлах заголовков (`*.h` файлах) и включаем этот файл заголовка везде, где это необходимо.

Включение заголовочного файла директивой `#include` равносильно копированию содержимого заголовочного файла.

Уже как структурировать конкретно вашу программу по директориям и файлам зависит от вашей архитектуры от того как вы планируете спроектировать программу.